# Problems with Twitter API (codebird)

Tags: php, ubuntu, twitter

I'm trying to post a simple text on Twitter now for a while, but it doesn't work.
I did exactly the steps of [this tutorial](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/auto_post_on_twitter_with_php), but it doesn't work.. Can anyone help me please?

Code:

```
<?php

// require codebird
require_once('codebird.php');
echo $test_import;

\Codebird\Codebird::setConsumerKey("myConsumerKey", "myConsumerSecret");
$cb = \Codebird\Codebird::getInstance();
$cb->setToken("myAccessToken", "myAccessTokenSecret");

$params = array(
  'status' => 'Auto Post on Twitter with PHP http://goo.gl/OZHaQD #php #twitter'
);
$reply = $cb->statuses_update($params);

?>
```

I have:
Ubunutu (on VMWare) 14.04

PHP 5.5.9
All files (codebird.php, cacert.pem and the file above) are in the same directory.

PS: The import of codebird.php works.

Comment: You probably don't want to expose your keys on a public site.

Comment: the reply is $test_import (= the file codebird.php was successfully imported)

Comment: Ok, the Problem is solved! The issue was, that I had deleted the minus in the Access-Token.